# Delete row using gridview_rowdeleting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I'm trying to delete a row in Grid View programmatically
I have created this GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="HeaderTables" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    EmptyDataText="There is no data record to display"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CellPadding="0" Height="0px" Width="800px"
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile_phone" HeaderText="Mobile number"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="street_number" HeaderText="Street number"/>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and my code behind is:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this data?",
   "Confirm delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {

        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySqlString"].ConnectionString);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("DELETE FROM persons WHERE id = @id", conn);
        MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter();

        try
        {
            int rowID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowID);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error:
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grid doesn't set the DataKeyNames property, so this grid isn't tracking any datakeys. Probably thats why you are getting an index error.

You should set the DataKeyNames property. In your code you also need to check to make sure the collection contains elements.The datakeys collection itself may not be null, but it can contain zero elements.

Comment: Where should I add the DataKeyName property? Can you write me a code what you think will work. I search all over the internet, but can't find anything that will work for me.

Comment: If you have taken datakey(OR Primary key) in your table "persons" then you must mention DataKeyNames="id" in your grid. Here i'm taking "id" as your datakey


Just add DataKeyNames="id" in your grid after `<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="HeaderTables" runat="server" AllowPaging="True"` in your aspx page

Comment: This is what I'm getting when adding DataKeyName="id  "DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'

Comment: that means you don't have column(field) with name ID in your table persons,do u have any primary key attribute in your table?

Comment: I have "id" column in table "persons", which is primary key.

Comment: can you please share your c# code and how you are binding the grid?

Comment: MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mySqlString"].ConnectionString);string selectString = "SELECT * FROM full_table";  
        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(selectString, conn);  
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();  
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);  
        this.GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];  
        this.GridView1.DataBind();  
        conn.Close();

Comment: you are binding your grid from "full_table" not "persons",that's why it is giving such an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use **DataKeyNames="ID"**  like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" CssClass="HeaderTables" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    EmptyDataText="There is no data record to display" DataKeyNames="ID"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CellPadding="0" Height="0px" Width="800px"
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile_phone" HeaderText="Mobile number"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="street_number" HeaderText="Street number"/>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Then it will work for you

Comment: I'm getting this error: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'ID'.

Comment: id will be the name of the column on which based you are deleting

Answer (score 0):

Your forgot to add DataKeyNames to your gridview

```
DataKeyNames="Valid Column Name" //Column name here instead of Valid Column name
```

Full Code below :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" DataKeyNames="Valid Column Name"  CssClass="HeaderTables" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
    EmptyDataText="There is no data record to display"
    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    CellPadding="0" Height="0px" Width="800px"
    onpageindexchanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging" 
    onsorting="GridView1_Sorting" onrowdeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="first_name" HeaderText="First name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="last_name" HeaderText="Last name"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="mobile_phone" HeaderText="Mobile number"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="city" HeaderText="City"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="street_number" HeaderText="Street number"/>

        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ButtonType="Button" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
</asp:GridView>
```