# GridView id null in Delete method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hi I have a GridView that I load in Edit Mode.  I then have an update button and a delete button that allows the user to to either update the data, or delete a row.  For some reason the delete method is not working, the id that I'm passing is coming up null and I can't figure out why.  My Gridview code is below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
        <asp:TemplateField>                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%--<asp:Label ID="lblID" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("intExaminerID") %>'></asp:Label>--%>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("intExaminerID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOID"  Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("sintDOLDistrictOfficeID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">                
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFName" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharFirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtLName" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharLastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharEmailAddress") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Extension">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharPhoneExtension") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="SSN Block">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSNStart" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharSSNBlockStart") %>' Width="5em"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSSNEnd" Visible='<%# IsInEditMode %>' runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("vcharSSNBlockEnd") %>' Width="5em"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action(s)">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" />
                <%--<asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" OnClick="UpdateRow" />--%>
                <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.CommandName == "Update"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];


            //Label id = (Label)row.FindControl("lblID");
            TextBox id = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtID");
            TextBox doid = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtDOID");
            TextBox fname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFName");
            TextBox lname = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLName");
            TextBox email = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtEmail");
            TextBox phone = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtPhone");
            TextBox start = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtSSNStart");
            TextBox end = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtSSNEnd");

            DOLBLL.UpdateExaminers(Convert.ToInt32(id.Text), Convert.ToInt16(doid.Text), fname.Text, lname.Text, email.Text, phone.Text, start.Text, end.Text);


        }

        if ((e.CommandName == "Delete"))
        {
            int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[index];

            TextBox id = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtID");

            DOLBLL.deleteClaimExaminer(Convert.ToInt32(id.Text));
        }

    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to set the DataKeyNames property to get the index working properly.

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18871621/delete-row-using-gridview-rowdeleting-event)

Comment: Hink.  Thanks a lot.  Can't believe I didn't think of that.  :)